# Can a gcc program detect when link time optimization (-flto) is enabled?

Tags: gcc, avr-gcc, lto

I have some code that MUST have link time optimization enabled to work correctly.   I need constant expression evaluation of:

```
  extern const char[] PROGMEM constantTable = {1,2,3,4,5};
    :
   char x = constantTable[4];
```

(PROGMEM is an avr-gcc construct that puts the constant in a separate memory section that is subsequently loaded into flash rather than ram, and *at execution time* will need special care to access.   But not at compile time...)

Is there some way that I can detect at compile time (or link time) that -flto has NOT been specified, so that I can issue an error message?

I have already compared the pre-defined symbols with and without -flto using the "-dM -E" trick, and there don't seem to be any differences.  Any idea for other tricks?

(should __builtin_constant_p() be "evaluated" at link time for -flto?  It isn't as of gcc 5.4.0 (latest "vendor supported" avr compiler.))

Comment: So PROGMEN won't working properly without -flto? What are the repercussions? Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: PROGMEM works fine, and is somewhat of a red herring wrt to actual question (detecting whether -flto has been used.)  It's just WHY I need to know.
If -flto is in use, the compiler can access constantTable[4] and get 5 at compile time.  if -flto is NOT in use, then the runtime code would need to use pgm_read_byte(&constantTable[4])

Comment: The question body seems to contradict the title. Per title, you want the *program* to check for
`-flto`. That's *runtime*. Per question body, you want to check for `-flto` at *compiletime
or linktime*. Which surely shouldn't be a problem, since your buildsystem knows what
its compile/link options are.

Comment: I guess the title is a bit ambiguous.  I want to check at compile time, but from inside the source code.  The buildsystem may know that -flto is enabled, but I want a way for the source code to detect it, in case someone mucks up the build system.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to try to test an external global variable for an impossible value:

```
// foo.c
const int LTO_in_use = 1;
```

and

```
// bar.c
#include <stdio.h>
extern int LTO_in_use;
void LTO_Not_Enabled(void) __attribute__ (( error("") ));

int main() {
    if (LTO_in_use == 99) {
        LTO_Not_Enabled();
    }
}
```

Any global variable will work, as long as you know an impossible value.
If you do create a specifc new variable, it should never actually end up referenced in the runtime, so it will get GC'ed by lto anyway.